# how to resize easily a pstricks picture?

Tags: pstricks, pstricks-add

I test my figures in an standalone file, and when I obtain what I want, I pass to my main file with text.

How can I do to adapt the size?

Because, sometimes I want to put 3 images in a row and I need to resize the original pstricks pictures.

Suppose this code typed by Herbert in other post:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\newpsobject{pslineA}{psline}{linewidth=6\pslinewidth, linecolor=green}
\newpsobject{pslineB}{psline}{linewidth=10\pslinewidth, linecolor=red}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
  \psline(0,1)(5,1)
  \psline[linewidth=1mm](0,2)(5,2)
  \pslineA(0,3)(5,3)
  \pslineB(0,4)(5,4)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Are there any easy way with `psset/xunit/yunit`?

I thought that changing numbers in

```
\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=1cm}
```

I could obtain what I want, but... no! I change this values and the picture is with the same length.

Comment: there's a `psgraph` environment that allows you to specify the width and height

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the units (unit itself and linewidth) *does* resize the image:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\newpsobject{pslineA}{psline}{linewidth=6\pslinewidth, linecolor=green}
\newpsobject{pslineB}{psline}{linewidth=10\pslinewidth, linecolor=red}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
  \psline(0,1)(5,1)
  \psline[linewidth=1mm](0,2)(5,2)
  \pslineA(0,3)(5,3)
  \pslineB(0,4)(5,4)
\end{pspicture}\\[2cm]

\psset{unit =1.5cm, linewidth=1.5\pslinewidth}
\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
  \psline(0,1)(5,1)
  \psline[linewidth=1mm](0,2)(5,2)
  \pslineA(0,3)(5,3)
  \pslineB(0,4)(5,4)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that has no effect to the line width.

Comment: @Herbert: I modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

setting the linewidth as a multiple of `\pslinewidth` sets it as an *absolute* value, the reason why the `\psset{unit=1.5}` doesn't change the setting. Compare it with

```
\newpsobject{pslineA}{psline}{linewidth=0.05, linecolor=green}
\newpsobject{pslineB}{psline}{linewidth=0.2, linecolor=red}
```

which is a relative linewidth setting which refers to the current units, e.g. 1cm. Then you can say `\psset{unit=..}` or

```
\psscalebox{<value>}{%
  \begin{pspicture}(..)(..)
  ...
  \end{pspicture}}
```

for rescaling the `pspicture` environment.

Answer (score 1):

### Best practice suggestions

1. Lengths in PSTricks  accept either relative unit or absolute unit.

   a. Use relative unit for lengths that you might want to scale globally now or in the future. The best candidates for this case are coordinates such as in `\psframe(2,3)` which is a rectangle of width `2` relative unit and height `3` relative unit where these relative units based on the values given to `xunit` (=1cm by default) and `yunit` (=1cm by default).

   b. Use absolute unit for lengths that you might not want to scale globally now or in the future. The best candidate for this case, for example, is line width.
2. If you just want to scale the lengths of the relative unit, set the base unit via `unit`, `xunit`, `yunit` or `runit`. For more detailed descriptions for these, see the manual.
3. If you want to scale everything regardless of their units (either relative or absolute), use `\psscalebox`.  `\psscalebox` even scales the characters.
4. By using both `unit` (or its variants) and `\psscalebox`, you can adjust your diagrams to have proportional dimensions for both lengths and characters.

See how it works:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\newpsobject{pslineA}{psline}{linewidth=6\pslinewidth, linecolor=green}
\newpsobject{pslineB}{psline}{linewidth=10\pslinewidth, linecolor=red}

\def\foo#1{%
\psset{unit=#1}
\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
  \psline(0,1)(5,1)
  \psline[linewidth=1mm](0,2)(5,2)
  \pslineA(0,3)(5,3)
  \pslineB(0,4)(5,4)
    \rput(2.5,2.5){\color{cyan}$\displaystyle \frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\foo{1cm}\\
\psscalebox{3}{\foo{.5}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is also `\psresizebox` that was mentioned for a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264311/resize-pspicture-graphic?newreg=97cd34b75def4703bc05e131c675a04c). This approach rescales everything in the figure including text which can be beneficial if you don't want to to mess up alignment.
I use it to include pstricks images that I created with inkscape like this:

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\input{img/pstricksimage}}
```

Comment: This seems better-suited as a comment. Using `\resizebox` would change *everything*, including the size of the text/font used, which seems to be excluded/not referenced in the OP (and can be assumed to remain the same).

Comment: Sorry, didn't have enough rep. to comment other answers. Thanks for the hint that this resizes everything, I'll put that in the answer as well. For me this is indeed a major reason to use this approach as not rescaling the text can mess up alignment of text and lines that I do in inkscape...