# Resize pspicture graphic

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pstricks

I have a simple SVG which I exported to a pspicture using Inkscape (*colors don't get exported, but that is unrelated*). I want to use it full with on a A1 poster and thought a pspicture vector graphic is way to achive this.

Everything is OK using A4 paper size. However using A3 and larger, the graphic is not displayed anymore.

I am using

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\input{inkscape.tex}}
\end{document}
```

but inlined the `inkscape.tex` for the MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    %LaTeX with PSTricks extensions
    %%Creator: 0.48.5
    %%Please note this file requires PSTricks extensions
    \psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}
    \begin{pspicture}(560,422)
    {
    \newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
    \pscustom[linewidth=0,linecolor=curcolor]
    {
    \newpath
    \moveto(26,403)
    \lineto(99,170)
    \lineto(325,273)
    \closepath
    }
    }
    {
    \newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
    \pscustom[linewidth=0,linecolor=curcolor]
    {
    \newpath
    \moveto(99,170)
    \lineto(325,273)
    \lineto(551,10)
    \closepath
    }
    }
    {
    \newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
    \pscustom[linewidth=0,linecolor=curcolor]
    {
    \newpath
    \moveto(26,403)
    \lineto(325,273)
    \lineto(546,406)
    \closepath
    }
    }
    {
    \newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
    \pscustom[linewidth=0,linecolor=curcolor]
    {
    \newpath
    \moveto(325,273)
    \lineto(551,10)
    \lineto(546,406)
    \closepath
    }
    }
    {
    \newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
    \pscustom[linewidth=0,linecolor=curcolor]
    {
    \newpath
    \moveto(26,403)
    \lineto(99,170)
    \lineto(42,41)
    \closepath
    }
    }
    {
    \newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
    \pscustom[linewidth=0,linecolor=curcolor]
    {
    \newpath
    \moveto(99,170)
    \lineto(551,10)
    \lineto(42,41)
    \closepath
    }
    }
    \end{pspicture}
}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Change the paper size to `\usepackage[a3paper]{geometry}` does not print any graphic.

Comment: This works for me. Please explain your compilation routine, make sure to have your system up to date, and make sure that this is not a rendering issue (try other viewers, try to zoom in and out).

Comment: I could not get it to work. However exporting from Inkscape to pdf and including it did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one, it is the correct PSTricks code.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \psset{unit=.5pt}
    \begin{pspicture}(560,422)
    \psline(99,170)(26,403)(325,273)(551,10)(99,170)
    \psline(42,41)(99,170)(325,273)(546,406)
    \pspolygon(42,41)(551,10)(546,406)(26,403)
    \end{pspicture}%
}
\end{document}
```